# List[Map[String,A]] to database table in scalaquery

Tags: scala, collections, relational-algebra, scalaquery, database-table

I just learnt about scalaquery yesterday and it seems useful. I'd like to convert a List[Map[String,A]] (where A is a primitive type - Int, Float, String etc. and the set of keys in each of the maps are the same) to a database table. I couldn't find examples of dynamic table creation in scalaquery (where the number of columns, i.e., the number of keys is dynamic).

Basically, I am interested in doing some relational algebra on this (and related) collections. Figured scalaquery would be the way to go. If not, please suggest alternatives.

Comment: String is not a primitive type.

Comment: Relational algebra operates on relations, not on collections.  That's why it's called relational algebra in the first place ...

Comment: "User unknown" - I believe the technical term for what I am referring to is value class.

Comment: Erwin Smout - The collection I am dealing with here - List[Map[String,A]] - represents a relation. I'd like to transform it into an equivalent representation of a relation which permits operations for relational algebra.

Comment: I have a similar issue. Have you found a solution for that?